# Slow Internet connection on Zorin OS

Tags: wifi, internet, zorin

These days I'm having a pretty bad connection to the Internet. Sometimes it works as usual but at other times it is very slow. The connection is bad only on Zorin, on my phone it works fine. What should I do? These are the speed tests that I have obtained:

```
user@zorin:~$ speedtest-cli
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from Yoigo (xxx.xx.xx.xx)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by Grupo MasMovil (Madrid) [1.28 km]: 7.976 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 23.02 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 3.79 Mbit/s

user@zorin:~$ speedtest-cli
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from Yoigo (xxx.xx.xx.xx)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by Grupo MasMovil (Madrid) [1.28 km]: 7.995 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 25.07 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 3.82 Mbit/s
```

My phone speed test:

Download: 96.2 Mbit/s

Upload: 104 Mbit/s

Answer (score 0):

If you have Qualcomm Atheros wifi adapter you can try disable hardware crypto support.

```
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=0" > /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

https://zoringroup.com/forum/5/6941/